# Join the date & time of two time_t values

Tags: c++, datetime, time

I've written a function that I believe will join the date component from one time_t and the time component from another:

```
time_t joinDateTime( time_t date, time_t time )
{
    tm tm_date( *gmtime( &date ) ), tm_time( *gmtime( &time ) );

    tm_date.tm_hour = tm_time.tm_hour;
    tm_date.tm_min = tm_time.tm_min;
    tm_date.tm_sec = tm_time.tm_sec;

    return mktime( &tm_date );
}
```

This function should not perform any timezone conversions, but `mktime()` apparently assumes the time structure you give it is in your local time zone, and converts it to UTC 0. How can I modify this function to not apply the time zone conversion that `mktime()` provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `time_t` is always in UTC time. If that's what you want, there's a more direct way to join the date and time. Since the measurement is in seconds, you can divide to get days and take the remainder for the time.

```
time_t joinDateTime( time_t date, time_t time )
{
    time_t days = date / (24*60*60);
    time_t seconds = time % (24*60*60);

    return days*24*60*60 + seconds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; this is definitely a better and more robust solution (I was hoping for a more simplified implementation in general).

Answer (score 0):

gmtime

```
struct tm * gmtime ( const time_t * timer );
```

Convert time_t to tm as UTC time

The conversion happens when you use the gmtime

Use `struct tm * localtime ( const time_t * timer );` instead